# Postgres-15.5 Confused about result of a Query

Tags: postgresql

i have the following query and I am a bit confused about the result of the query.

```
SELECT a.row_number
     , a.*
     , a.km
     , b.km         AS km_alone
     , a.km <> b.km AS unequal_km
FROM (SELECT *
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS row_number
      FROM schema.my_view
      ORDER BY modified_at DESC) AS a
         INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS row_number
                     FROM schema.my_view
                     ORDER BY modified_at DESC) AS b ON a.row_number = b.row_number
WHERE a.km <> b.km;
```

What I'm doing here is basically running the same query two times and compare one column of the two results with each other. So I'm expecting to get an empty result because if I run the exact same query two times, there shouldn't be any difference if no write-operation was done on the queried tables which is not the case. But the query returns some results where the two queries have differences. However, if I delete the a.* from resultset like this:

```
SELECT a.row_number
     , a.km
     , b.km         AS km_alone
     , a.km <> b.km AS unequal_km
FROM (SELECT *
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS row_number
      FROM schema.my_view
      ORDER BY modified_at DESC) AS a
         INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS row_number
                     FROM schema.my_view
                     ORDER BY modified_at DESC) AS b ON a.row_number = b.row_number
WHERE a.km <> b.km;
```

I got what I expected: An empty result-set. Because I'm relatively new to postgres I don't understand why just adding columns to the result changes the result itself. I would always expect an empty resultset, no matter how many columns I have in the result-set. Can you explain why this is not the case here?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
As @jjanes and @JohnH suggested i need to add an `ORDER BY` clause at each `ROW_NUMBER()` function. The column that is used in the `ORDER BY` clause needs to be unique to get a deterministic result in each subquery.

```
SELECT a.row_number
     , a.*
     , a.km
     , b.km         AS km_alone
     , a.km <> b.km AS unequal_km
FROM (SELECT *
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_number
      FROM schema.my_view) AS a
         INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_number
                     FROM schema.my_view) AS b ON a.row_number = b.row_number
WHERE a.km <> b.km;
```

Comment: If modified_at can have ties then your ordering is not deterministic. Which means row_number is not either, which means the join is not deterministic.

Comment: Hypothesis is, in last case subquery result is materialized and self joined. In first case, 2 subqueries runned separately and then joined, because column list in this subqueries different - so, table scanning my be different. This case commented above by @JJanes. See execution plan for both variant.

Comment: The expression `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` is non-deterministic because there is no explicit ordering specified for the function. The sorting that occurs in the each subquery's `ORDER BY` occurs after `ROW_NUMBER` has been evaluated. As @jjanes mentioned, sort order will also be non-deterministic if `modified_at` is not unique. Adding `ORDER BY` to the `ROW_NUMBER` function with sufficient columns to have a unqiue sort order would give the results you expect.

Comment: Hello commentators,
thank you very much for your recommendations. The solution was to add the primary key of the `my_view` table in the `ORDER BY` clause. Now I have an empty result-set, no matter how many columns I'm selecting. Thank you @JohnH and @jjanes for your help. Thank you @ValNik also for suggesting to look into the query plan. Looking into the query plan was very helpfull.